# How to solve these two differential equation?

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, matlab, systems-of-equations, boundary-value-problem

I try to solve these two difference equation ;

$$
\frac{dq}{dz} = -j\left(b_1q - kp\right),\\
\frac{dp}{dz} = -j\left(b_2p - kq\right)
$$

where $j$ stands for $\sqrt{-1}$, and $b_1$ ,$b_2$ and k are constants and $q(0)$, $p(0)$ are initial values and $z \in [0, 10]$.

I try to solve these equations analytically by assuming a general formula for the solution on the form $\exp(Cz)$ (where $C$ is a constant) and substitute this form into the two equations and get the solution shown in the attached image where $A$, $B$, $D$ constant related to $b_1$, $b_2$, $k$.

Is this solution correct or not? I try to get the solution numerically using matlab (using ode45 function) but I didn't get the same answer

[image]

Comment: In the second equation, should the term $b_2p$ be $b_2q$?  Or isthe $-kp$ supposed to be $-kq$?  It seems likely that one of those is true.

Comment: The original version featured $z = [0 \, 10]$ what was that supposed to mean?

Comment: @RossMillikan yes it should be a $kq$ in the second equation. My error.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of guessing an ansatz you can try to calculate the matrix $e^{Az}$ instead, once you put your first order system into matrix form:

$$
\underbrace{
\frac{d}{dz}
\left[
\begin{matrix}
q \\
p
\end{matrix}
\right]
}_{x'}
=
\underbrace{
\left[
\begin{matrix}
-i b_1 & i k \\
i k & -i b_2
\end{matrix}
\right]
}_A
\,
\underbrace{
\left[
\begin{matrix}
q \\
p
\end{matrix}
\right]
}_x 
\iff x'(z) = A \, x(z)
$$

this has the solution

$$
x(z) = e^{Az} x(0)
$$

Verifying your solution is just a matter of putting the solutions into the differential equation system and check if they fullfill them.

You should rather use a computer algebra system, if you don't like to calculate the derivatives by hand. Checking the numerical values is not bad as a first test, but less ensuring.

Comment: which computer program should i use to solve this type of problem numerically ?